# “Out of Gas” while transferring ethereum from account to contract

Tags: testing, ethereum

I am using ganache to create 10 ethereum accounts. I want to transfer ethereum from one account to a smart contract. I am doing this by writing two following smart contracts in solidity;

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.6.0;
contract Ether_Transfer_To{
    function () external payable { //fallback function

    }
    function get_balance() public returns(uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
contract Ether_Transfer_From{
    Ether_Transfer_To private the_instance;
    constructor() public{
        //the_instance=Ether_Transfer_To(address(this));
        the_instance=new Ether_Transfer_To();
    }
    function get_balance() public returns(uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }
    function get_balance_of_instance() public returns(uint){
        //return address(the_instance).balance;
        return the_instance.get_balance();
    }
    function () external payable {
        // msg.sender.send(msg.value)
        address(the_instance).send(msg.value);
    }
}
```

When I deploy the `contract Ether_Transfer_From` smart contract then I get its three-member functions as follows in [remix](http://remix.ethereum.org/#appVersion=0.7.7&optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.5.1+commit.c8a2cb62.js);

[image]

But when I sent one 1 Wei from account to smart contract by writing 1 in the text box and clicking on a (fallback) button, then I get the following error;

> transact to Ether_Transfer_From. (fallback) errored: VM Exception while
>   processing transaction: out of gas

I followed the answer of the same [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44410/remix-ide-transact-to-errored-vm-exception-while-processing-transaction) by installing `Ganache-cli 7.0.0 beta.0` by using following command;

> npm install -g ganache-cli@7.0.0-beta.0

But I still get the same error. I think I am using older Ganache cli instead of `Ganache-cli 7.0.0 beta.0` as it goes to C drive and I installed `ganache 2.1.1` in D drive previously.

I just want to send ethereum from one account to other but I am really stuck in this `out of gas` Error. **If there is any way to remove this error or transfer ethereum from one account to another then please let me know.**

Comment: then just delete the old version of ganache

Comment: yes I did it in newer version there is no such problem

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I did for one of my projects.

This snippet, deploys the compiles the solidity file and then deploys it and gets the address of the deployed contract address

```
  const input = fs.readFileSync('Migrations.sol');
  const output = solc.compile(input.toString(), 1);
  const bytecode = output.contracts[':Migrations']['bytecode'];
  const abi = JSON.parse(output.contracts[':Migrations'].interface);
  var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);

  contract.deploy({
      data: '0x'+bytecode,
  })
  .send({
      from: chairPerson,
      gas: 5500000,
      gasPrice: '2000000000000'
  })
  .on('receipt', (receipt) => {
       add=receipt.contractAddress;
  })
```

Now using contract's abi, I can call methods of the deployed contract and use the following code to transfer '1.5' ether from one address to another.

```
contract.methods.registerRequest(fromAddress,toAddress,requestNumber).send({from:fromAddress,value : web3.utils.toWei('1.5', 'ether')}).on('transactionHash', (hashResult) => {-- some code--})
```

And also make the method in the solidity as payable to allow it to transfer ether, like :

```
function registerRequest(address requestedBy,address requestedTo,uint requestNumber) payable public{}
```

Refer : https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id12

> Basically I used web3 api itself to transfer ether from one account
>   to another by calling my solidity method.
>
> Also, check the following things :
>    1. While deploying, are you deploying with enough gas ? I faced this error when I was deploying the contract with less gas quantity
>    2. Your method in solidity should be payable